# Can not connect to my database server using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to build a profile page system for users bare in mind I'm real new to php. In the code below, I get the error message I specified it to echo, when i cannot connect to my database ie :

> "could not connect to server"

I dont get any other error messages, only this. I cant seem to find the problem, any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code :

```
<?php
include_once 'Header.php';
?>

<?php

if (isset($_GET['user_uid'])) 
    $user_uid = $_GET['user_uid']; 

mysqli_connect($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);
mysqli_select_db($conn, "users") or die ("could not connect to server");
$userquery = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM users where user_uid='$user_uid'") 
or die ("The Query could not be completed, contact an administrator");

if (mysql_num_rows($userquery) != 1) {
    die ("that username could not be found");
}
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($userquery, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $first = $row['first'];
    $last = $row['last'];
    $city = $row['city'];
    $country = $row['country'];
}
?>


<table width="398" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td height="26" colspan="2">Your Profile Information </td>
    <td><div align="right"><a href="index.php">logout</a></div></td>
  </tr>
  <?php echo $first; ?>
  <tr>
    <td width="129" rowspan="5"><img src="<?php echo $picture ?>" width="129" 
  height="129" alt="no image found"/></td>
    <td width="82" valign="top"><div align="left">FirstName:</div></td>
    <td width="165" valign="top"><?php echo $first ?></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td valign="top"><div align="left">LastName:</div></td>
    <td valign="top"><?php echo $last ?></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top"><div align="left">City:</div></td>
    <td valign="top"><?php echo $city ?></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td valign="top"><div align="left">Country:</div></td>
    <td valign="top"><?php echo $country ?></td>
  </tr>

</table>
<p align="center"><a href="index.php"></a></p>


<?php
include_once 'Footer.php';
?>
```

Comment: This looks like a botched conversion from `mysql_`.  `mysqli_connect()` returns the connection, so store that.  It also selects the database, so no need for `mysqli_select_db()`.  Also you need the connection handle for the various other mysqli_ calls.

Comment: And `mysql_num_rows` is dead too... which seems to still remain in that code.

Comment: You get that error message because your error reporting code is `die ("could not connect to server")`. You probably want `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` instead ([source](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/error_reporting)).

Comment: I don't see `$conn` being defined anywhere - unless that's part of `Header.php`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, the whole layout I was using was wrong, for making a live profile page, this new layout fixed the problems :)...

```
<?php
 include_once 'RoadieHeader.php';
 ?>

<?php

//PULLING OUT USERNAME//
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "select user_uid from users where user_uid 
='".$_SESSION['u_uid']."'");

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

$uid = ucfirst($row['user_uid']); 

//PULLING OUT EVERYTHING!//
$result_f =  mysqli_query($conn, "select user_first from users where 
user_first ='".$_SESSION['u_first']."'");

$row_f = mysqli_fetch_array($result_f);

 $first = ucfirst($row_f['user_first']);

$last = ucfirst($_SESSION['u_last']);

$city = ucfirst($_SESSION['u_city']);

$country = ucfirst($_SESSION['u_country']);

 $about =  ucfirst($_SESSION['u_about']);

?>


<table width="398" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
     <td height="26" colspan="2"><?php echo $uid ?></td>
    <td><div align="right"><a href="index.php">logout</a></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td width="129" rowspan="5"><img src="<?php echo $picture ?>" 
 width="129" height="129" alt="no image found"/></td>
    <td width="82" valign="top"><div align="left">FirstName:</div></td>
    <td width="165" valign="top"><?php echo $first ?></td>
  </tr>

   <tr>
    <td valign="top"><div align="left">LastName:</div></td>
      <td valign="top"><?php echo $last ?></td>
    </tr>

 <tr>
  <tr>
     <td valign="top"><div align="left">City:</div></td>
     <td valign="top"><?php echo $city ?></td>
   </tr>

  <tr>
    <td valign="top"><div align="left">Country:</div></td>
    <td valign="top"><?php echo $country ?></td>
  </tr>

  <tr> 
    <td valign="top"><div align="left">About me: </div></td>
    <td valign="top">
      <?php echo $about ?>
     </td>
  </tr>

</table>
<p align="center"><a href="index.php"></a></p>


  <?php
  include_once 'RoadieFooter.php';
 ?>
```

I forgot the current user's ID's are stored in $_SESSION when they log in, and is carried page to page on session_start()

Answer (score 0):

It is *specifically* dying because of `$conn` - that doesn't appear to be set anywhere.

However in saying that, as has been pointed out, you don't *need* to use `mysqli_select_db` in `mysqli` as it's all done in the `mysqli_connect` function.

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);
```

That is enough - you *only* need the `mysqli_db` to *change* the current DB, but even then it needs a **valid** link identifier (the result returned by `mysqli_connect`).

So, that would be:

```
mysqli_select_db($conn, "users") or die ("could not connect to server");
```

...as long as `$conn` is **valid**.